# Java library for massive sequential write to files

Tags: java, database, performance, file-io

In my application I need to write a lot of data into DB. To speed it up I was thinking about writing to sequential binary files in real time and then doing bulk inserts into DB. There are different logging libraries that can be configured to create new file every x seconds or MB, but they are slowing down the system significantly under heavy load and they work with string messages.

Are there any performant libraries for binary files?

Comment: How does `FileOutputStream`, probably buffered with `BufferedOutputStream` work for you in terms of performance? Can you not just use those and simply switch files yourself periodically? What does your data throughput rate need to be, and what do your disks support?

Comment: _premature optimization is the root of all evil_, did you you test with (db connection pool) that this is the real bootleneck ?

Comment: Expected write rate is about 0.5MB/sec and I prefer to leave the hard work such as synch and file rolling to libraries. I'm not considering direct write to DB because there are lots of small records and it's not practical to commit each record separately. Besides, I do not need that data in real time, but for later data-mining.

Comment: 500 KB/second isn't that much. I would close the files in a background ExecutorService so it won't impact your latency. I have written a library which can handle hundreds of MB per second and I would only roll the files once per day esp if you are only going to load them once per day.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I'd look into the possibility of using JDBC batch inserts. The relevant methods are [`PreparedStatement.addBatch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#addBatch%28%29) and [`Statement.executeBatch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch%28%29).

Here is a tutorial that discusses them: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2012/03/batch-insert-in-java-jdbc.html

In my experience (with PostgreSQL), they are a lot faster than single inserts. It could well be the case that they'll be fast enough for your purposes.

Comment: I know about the batch inserts. That's why I mentioned the bulk insert from sequential files. My question actually is how to prepare these files.

Comment: @Dima: The batch inserts that I am talking about require no files.

Comment: Yes, but records created by several threads at their own time, so I'm not sure that accumulating these records in memory would be a good idea.

Comment: @Dima You can combine that with a commit() every N rows or some time frame (.5 second timeout). That minimizes the in-memory component.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka is designed to be able to act as a unified platform for handling all the real-time data feeds.
https://kafka.apache.org/08/design.html